# Set marker in the callback function where user's position is available after creating the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I made a function that display nearest hotels in google map.my code is as follow.

```js
var map;

  function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.535516,77.391026);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      try {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var myLocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          setPos(myLocation);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        var myLocation = {
          lat: 25.2048,
          lng: 55.2708
        };
        setPos(myLocation);
      }
    } else {
      var myLocation = {
        lat: 25.2048,
        lng: 55.2708
      };
      setPos(myLocation);
    }
  }

  function setPos(myLocation) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: myLocation,
      zoom: 10
    });
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: myLocation,
      radius: 4000,
      types: ['hotels']
    }, processResults);
  }

  function processResults(results, status, pagination) {
    if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      return;
    } else {
      createMarkers(results);
    }
  }

  function createMarkers(places) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var placesList = document.getElementById('places');
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) 
    {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
```

```css
html,body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      height: 500px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 800px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuBzeYkYimIquGG5KkIcB6vFmtHMUzDFo&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuBzeYkYimIquGG5KkIcB6vFmtHMUzDFo&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Above Example Returns me nearest hotels around user location. but i wants to *also display users location pointer*.
So how can i show users location here.

i also try by custom adding in `initMap()` function to show users location marker but it **OVERRIDE** with Hotels icons. so when i refresh page first for microseconds user location shows and than hotels icon will override that.
here is my image with o/p of above code.

[Output of Fiddle Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFMjI.png)

Comment: How did you try to show the user's position?  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your problem.

Comment: i place code at starting of function. first i get user lat long and than place marker to there at starting of `initMap()` Function.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you mean.  The geolocation functionality is asynchronous, you need to set that marker in the callback function where/when the user's position is available (and after creating the map...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the creation of the marker to the `setPos` function (where the geolocation results are available and the map has been create.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lxk4x4d7/1/)

when geolocation fails:
[image: screenshot of resulting map on http (when geolocation fails)]

when geolocation works, it shows my current location.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function error() {
  console.log("error!")
  var myLocation = {
    lat: 25.2048,
    lng: 55.2708
  };
  setPos(myLocation);
}

function initMap() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.535516, 77.391026);

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    try {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var myLocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        setPos(myLocation);
      }, error);
    } catch (err) {
      var myLocation = {
        lat: 25.2048,
        lng: 55.2708
      };
      setPos(myLocation);
    }
  } else {
    var myLocation = {
      lat: 25.2048,
      lng: 55.2708
    };
    setPos(myLocation);
  }
}

function setPos(myLocation) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: myLocation,
    zoom: 10
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLocation,
    map: map,
    title: "My Position"
  })
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: myLocation,
    radius: 4000,
    types: ['hotels']
  }, processResults);
}

function processResults(results, status, pagination) {
  if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    return;
  } else {
    createMarkers(results);
  }
}

function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var placesList = document.getElementById('places');
  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: place.name,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: thank you brother it works for me. but problem is it shows two markers in my div and its location is not exact. can you help >